# Error implement Google Maps script with places library on Ionic

Tags: angular, google-apps-script, ionic-framework, google-places-api

Implementing the Google Places Autocomplete on my Ionic project, i get the next messages in console:

Warrent -> Google Maps JavaScript API has been loaded directly without a callback. This is not supported and can lead to race conditions and suboptimal performance. For supported loading patterns please see https://goo.gle/js-api-loading
polyfills.js:1 [webpack-dev-server] Server started: Hot Module Replacement disabled, Live

Error -> You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.

Error -> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'wy')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'wy')

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>App</title>
    <base href="/" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script async
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Api_Key&libraries=places&v=weekly">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

component:

```
initAutocomplete(): void {
  const address1Field = document.querySelector(
    '#ship-address'
  ) as HTMLInputElement;
  let autocomplete: google.maps.places.Autocomplete;

  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(address1Field, {
    componentRestrictions: { country: ['es', 'uk'] },
    fields: ['address_components', 'geometry'],
    types: ['address'],
  });
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);

  function fillInAddress() {
    const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    let address1 = '';    
    for (const component of place.address_components as google.maps.GeocoderAddressComponent[]) {
      const componentType = component.types[0];
        switch (componentType) {
          case 'street_number': {
            address1 = `${component.long_name} ${address1}`;
            break;
          }
          case 'route': {
            address1 += component.short_name;
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      address1Field.value = address1;
    }
  }
```

layout:

```
<ion-fab
  class="input-search-fab mt-per-10 input-shadow"
  vertical="top"
  horizontal="start"
  slot="fixed"
>  
  <form (click)="checkKeyboard()">
    <input
      id="input-searchbar"
      class="input-search"
      type="text"
      [placeholder]="'home.search' | translate"
      [formControl]="control"
    />
  </form>
</ion-fab>
```

Similar [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/place-autocomplete-addressform-f2lj83), migration of the example in the [official](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform#maps_places_autocomplete_addressform-html) documentation to angular. Unlike this codesandbox, in my project, the list of autocomplete references is not even shown.